# Windows 7-Windows 7 dual boot issue

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

My system has 2x320GB hard drives,each has a Windows 7 x64 installation, one for work and other for home, with prompt at boot to select an OS at boot.

I clean installed Windows 7 on the "home" hard drive recently(overwriting the old "home" one), after which I was able to boot into both home and work.

But now my system directly boots into the work Windows 7. Both hard drives are still detected. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-installing the home Win7, I made some changes to the HDD it was on. I created a partition out of some unallocated space the hdd had, which resulted in the HDD being converted to a dynamic disc(having 4 primary partitions). When this happens, Windows Disk Management warns you that you won't be able to boot from the drive.

However, EasyBCD and Windows Startup & Recovery still listed the Windows installation in the boot menus which resulted in me chasing an unattainable dream.

I unallocated the partitions and converted the HDD to a basic disc(using EASUS Partition Manager, I guess Disk Management would do too.) and restarted the box and voila!

Update: Did something similar the other day, with Gparted and I was working with 4 partitions on one disk(1 primary, 1 extended with three logical. wonder why I couldn't get that configuration on the win7 box?)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in the *Startup and Recovery* settings and see if the "**Time to display list of operating systems**" option is set.  If not, this causes the default to boot without prompting.

[image]

You can get to it through *Control Panel*, *System*, *Advanced* tab and then by clicking the *Settings* button under the *Startup and Recovery* sub heading.

Alternatively, [**EasyBCD**](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) is very useful for editing the boot options if this fails to help.

Comment: Time to display was enabled and EasyBCD showed a boot menu with the two Windows 7 entries. However, my pc would still boot into my work Win7.

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup like this as well and the most reliable way to handle this is with a boot manager (I am using BootIT http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/bootit-next-generation.htm but there are others including a few open source ones). The primary advantage is when you boot through the boot manager it correctly toggles the active partition and the 2 installs can behave as truly independent. The other advantage is if you reinstall you boot into the partition you want to reinstall and any changes don't affect the other install.